# for-in and in of JS

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

```
var result = function(){}
console.log("constructor" in result);//true
console.log("__proto__" in result);//true
console.log("prototype" in result);//true

for (var prop in result) {
   console.log(prop); // no output!!
}
```

when I use `in` for determining if property in the result, it returns true; But when I use `for-in`, there is no property in the result, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ref:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

> A for...in loop does not iterate over non–enumerable properties.
>   Objects created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have
>   inherited non–enumerable properties from Object.prototype and
>   String.prototype that are not enumerable, such as String's indexOf
>   method or Object's toString method. The loop will iterate over all
>   enumerable properties of the object or that it inherits from its
>   constructor's proptotype (including any which overwrite built-in
>   properties).

Answer (score 4):

That is because `for...in` only iterates over *enumerable* properties of its target. Enumerability is an attribute that properties may or may not have (along with writability and configurability); those that do not have it will not be exposed by `for...in` even though they of course still exist on the object.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) says this for `for...in`:

> A for...in loop does not iterate over non–enumerable properties.
>   Objects created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have
>   inherited non–enumerable properties from Object.prototype and
>   String.prototype that are not enumerable, such as String's indexOf
>   method or Object's toString method. The loop will iterate over all
>   enumerable properties of the object or that it inherits from its
>   constructor's proptotype (including any which overwrite built-in
>   properties).

On the other hand, `in` does not take enumerability into account and so returns `true` if a property exists without further deliberation.

Answer (score 1):

Some properties are enumerables , some are not, so you wont see them in a for-in loop.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
for (var prop in result) {
  console.log(result[prop]); // no output!!
 }
```

`for..in` does not itererate they way you expect. `prop` is index and the loop runs for each element in `result`.

it is the same as
`for(var i =0;i<result.length;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

for ... in just only enumeration object members